# I cannot figure out the right media query to use for my window resize issue

Tags: css, media-queries

http://library.skybundle.com/

I need the two big icons to be horizontally side by side until the window is resized to be smaller (like that of a mobile phone, for example), and then when that happens, the orange one on the right should drop down below the green one to form a vertical layout.

I know I should use media queries, as I have been told, but I am not sure how to do this or which ones to use.

I am not great at CSS, but I am learning. I have done TONS of research, spent weeks trying to figure this out. Please help. Thanks!

Comment: Don't post a link to your production site, which will become meaningless as soon as the fix is applied. Show some code and a demonstration of the issue on something like http://jsfiddle.net.

Comment: @alex, ok thanks, I'm sorry - I'm still very new to all of this. Member of this site for only 2 days. I haven't used jsfiddle yet so I will go try to figure that out now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure this is below your other rule for `.skone-half`.

This should work

```
@media(max-width: 960px) {
    .skone-half {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Just comment if it doesn't.

Here's a really simplified version of that portion of your site in a fiddle.

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3YkRb/1/)

So according to that fiddle you can tell the code works. If you have problems implementing it let me know or if it just doesn't work for some other reason. You could also adjust the point in px it changes at if you want I just set it to when it breaks the width of the container.

**EDIT:**

Usually though you would want to change the width of the containing element from a fixed width to 100%, this way the images center, like this.

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tNma9/)

In your case you have two containers with widths that you need to change so it would look like this.

```
@media(max-width: 960px) {
    .skone-half {
        width: 100%;
    }
    #container, #head-content {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I wish people were more like you instead of just leaving a mean comment and giving me -1 when I'm just a noob in need haha.

Comment: Hey no problem.  A lot of people on this site are very helpful.  It does help to learn how to make a fiddle of your problem. (sometimes recreating the problem in a fiddle actually helps you fix the problem yourself, but not necessarily in this case.)  I do like how you sent a link to your production site as well, because honestly I think it more fully helps someone help you, but a fiddle is a important as well.  It's cool to hear that you're just starting out coding. It's good you showed research effort in your question. Hey I'm glad I could help. Good luck in your future coding! :)

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your css file:

```
/*if the screen is 800 pixels or less */
@media only screen and (min-width: 800px) {
    .page {width: 100%; } /*set your page class to be 100% width */
}
```

Comment: Ok, doing it now. Thanks, fingers crossed.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a starting point for your jsfiddle (which exihibits the side-by-side -> vertical layout!).

http://jsfiddle.net/gjGGw/1/

**HTML**

```
<img src="http://library.skybundle.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/PRODUCT_TRAINING2.png" />
<img src="http://library.skybundle.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/EDUCATIONAL_COURSES2.png" />
```

**CSS**

```
img{width:300px;height:300px;margin:0px 30px;}
```

Comment: Nick, THANKS! I really appreciate that! I opened up JSFiddle as soon as Alex mentioned it and was like UHHHHHH what do I do haha. Ok, so now I have a starting point. Wonderful! Appreciate it. And thanks to all who are bearing with me and providing any feedback. I'm very new to computer code, despite my months of research. No school - just self-taught.